# useMutation stuck in inifnite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to run a query that saves an entity in the database using usemutation. The problem is that the `saveVisa()` mutation gets stuck in an infinite loop (create the same element multiple times) and I don't know why this is happening.

```
import {React, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router' 
import { SAVE_VISA } from '../src/mutations/applyVisa';

import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";

const Payment = () => {

  const router = useRouter();
  var QRCode = require('qrcode');

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const { payment_id } = router.query;


  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
  }, []);

  // // Get QR code image source code
  var qr_code = "";
  var qr_url = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/visaconfirmation/${payment_id}`;

  var opts = {
    type: 'text'
  }

  QRCode.toString(qr_url, opts, function (err, url) {
    if (err) throw err
    qr_code = url;
  });

  var qr_code_image = qr_code.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");

  // // save visa
  
  const [saveVisa, { 
    data 
  }] = useMutation(SAVE_VISA, {
    variables: {
      payment_detail_id: payment_id,
      qr_url: qr_url,
      qr_image: qr_code_image,
      status: "Active"
    }
  });

  saveVisa();

  // Send Email

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='pt-10 text-center text-1xl'>Your Payment Was succesfully! Please Check your Email for more details.</h1>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Payment;
```

Comment: to me it looks like everytime the component updates saveVisa will run, not exactly sure what it does but if you only need to run it once maybe use useMemo or useEffect hook

Comment: You shouldn't be calling a mutation directly from render, call it in a callback or inside a `useEffect` - or don't call it at all, I'm not sure what it's trying to accomplish at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

`saveVisa` runs on every render. Since it's a mutation, it will make the page re-render, trapping you in an infinite loop.

To avoid this, as @Chris Li and @juliomalves suggested, you can use the `useEffect` hook with no dependencies, which will make this function only run on the first rendering of the page:

```
useEffect(() => {
    saveVisa();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`saveVisa` will call the mutation and get data from server.
so it will render the page and call `savevisa` again.
then will get data and render again ...